# How to parse a JSON document using jq when an array sometimes does not exist?

Tags: jq

I have a utility that gives me JSON data with varying structure. Sometimes an array is missing, and some times it's not missing.

For example, this is with the array missing:

```json
{
  "returned": 0,
  "total": 0
}
```

... and this is with the array included:

```json
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "Ident": "server:11ylb",
      "Ident2": "server:",
      "desc": "HOSE",
      "node": "servA"
    },
    {
      "Ident": "server:11yla",
      "Ident2": "server:",
      "numberOfRuns": 1,
      "desc": "CAR",
      "node": "servA"
    }
  ],
  "returned": 2,
  "total": 2
}
```

The problem is that if I try to iterate over the elements of the  `statutes` array when `total` is 0, I get an error:

```bash
$ utility | jq '.statuses.[]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

How may I avoid this error when the array is missing from the input?

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over the `statuses` array, use `.statuses[]?` if you believe that it may sometimes not exist.  The expression `.statuses[]?` is equivalent to `.statuses | .[]?`, i.e., it extracts the `statuses` value, and if it's a valid array continues with generating a set of the array elements from it.

For example, the following `jq` expression would give you a JSON array of all `desc` values in the `statuses` array, or an empty array if the `statuses` array does not exist:

```
[.statuses[]?.desc]
```

See also "[.[]?](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D?)" and "[Optional Object Identifier-Index: .foo?](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#optional-object-identifier-index)" in the `jq` manual.